# Help with this inequality : $-1 \le \frac{1+x^2}{2x} \le 1$

Tags: inequality

I  have to solve 
$$
-1 \le \frac{1+x^2}{2x} \le 1
$$ 
My attempt at solution:
$$ -1 ≤ (1+x²)/2x ≤ 1 $$
$$ - 1 ≤ (1+x²)/2x  \quad\text{and}\quad  (1+x²)/2x ≤ 1 $$
$$ 0≤(1+x²)/2x + 1   \quad\text{and}\quad (1+x²)/2x - 1   ≤0 $$
i.e. $(x²+2x+1)/2x   \quad\text{and}\quad (x²-2x+1)/2x $
$$ 0≤ (x+1)²/2x \quad\text{and}\quad  (x-1)²/2x  ≤0 $$
since the numerator is positive, the sign depends on the denominator
i.e. $\;0≤x$ and  $x≤0$
$$ 
therefore the answer is $0$ which is wrong as $1$ and $-1$ also satisfy the inequation and zero will make $(1+x²)/2x$ not defined, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've started converting your notes into MathJax; the examples I've given should be enough for you to continue. THere's a ton more information at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. You can edit your question (as I did) by clicking "edit" just beneath the question itself.  You might complain that this is a lot of work, but it parts of how we do things here.

Comment: Images are generally regarded as bad on MSE, because they're not searchable, so we ask that you type your mathematics. It's great that you've actually done some work on the problem and shown your work -- that makes it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: yup mathjax look like work

Comment: "yup mathjax look like work": You might want to consider that you're asking **us** to do work for **you**; there's an implicit bargain here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The domain of this inequation is $\mathbf R{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$, and it is equivalent to
$$\biggl|\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\biggr|\le 1\iff\frac{1+|x|^2}{2|x|}\le1,$$
so set $t=|x|$ and solve for $t$ first.

Comment: yup that gets the range but i wanted to know where did i go wrong

Comment: Well, can't this be an alternative answer? Your question might be useful to others as well.

Comment: Your last inequalities imply either both $x\ge 0$ and $x\le 0$, i.e. $x=0$,, but this is excluded (not in the domain of the inequation) , OR the first fraction is $0$ and the second is non-positive (whence $x=-1$)  OR  the first fraction is non-negative and the second is $0$ (whence $x=1$).

Answer (score 1):

By the arithmetic-geometric inequality, we have that
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{2}\geq\sqrt{1\cdot x^2}=|x|
$$
So immediately (as the LHS is positive):
$$
\left\vert\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right\vert\geq 1
$$
with equality iff $x^2=1$. Since we're looking for solutions to
$$
\left\vert\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right\vert\leq 1
$$
we must in fact have
$$
\left\vert\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right\vert= 1
$$
so that $x^2=1$ or $x=\pm1$

Answer (score 1):

This problem is equivalent to $$\left|\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right|\le 1,$$ which gives $$(1+x^2)^2\le(2x)^2,$$ which gives $$(1-x)^2(1+x)^2\le 0.$$ Since LHS of last inequality can never be negative, it follows that the only solution will occur when LHS vanishes. Can you continue now?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to consider two separate cases (x < 0 and x > 0). Note that x cannot be 0.

Case 1. When x > 0, we have

$ – 2x \le 1 + x^2 \le 2x$

I.e. ($0 \le (1 + x)^2$) and ($(1 – x)^2 \le 0$)

I.e. (All x) and (x = 1)

i.e. x = 1

Combining x = 1 with the ***initial x > 0***, we have x = 1.

Similarly, we get x = –1 from case 2.

Answer (score 0):

X= 1 , X = -1 only $$
LHS \;inequality \; \frac{1\,+\,x^2}{2x}\;+1\geq0 $$
$$\frac{(1\,+\,x)^2}{2x}\,\geq0 $$
There for x=-1 or x$\geq0$
$$ $$ Similarly RHS inequality x=1 or x$\le0$
$$ $$ Hence x=1 and x= -1 only